# Deleter of dynamically allocated array using unique_ptr called multiple times in Visual C++ 2012 express, but not it gcc 4.8

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-studio-2012, unique-ptr

I have run the following code in Visual C++ 2012 express edition

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main ()
{
   auto deleter=[&](int* ptr){ delete [] ptr; std::cout << "DeleterCalled " << std::endl; };
   std::unique_ptr<int[], decltype(deleter)> ptr1(new int[4], deleter);
   std::unique_ptr<int[], decltype(deleter)> ptr2(std::move(ptr1));
}
```

which gives the result as

```
Deleter Called
Deleter Called
```

However when I run the code after compiling using gcc 4.8 I get the following

```
Deleter Called
```

Why is the deleter called twice in VC++ where practically it seems that memory should be allocated only once, which implies that the deleter should also be called once.  The next operation is std::move which I think should only transfer the ownership to the new pointer.  However when I use gcc 4.8 it seems that the program is working as expected.

Comment: In VS 2015 I get only one "DeleterCalled" line. I suspect it's a bug in VS 2012.

Comment: You might want to print `ptr`. I suspect it passes `nullptr` in one case (for `ptr1`).

Comment: @Jaord42, yes I printed ptr in the deleter and I found that in visual studio it prints a null pointer, as in , `auto deleter=[&](int* ptr){ std::cout << "ptr : " << ptr << std::endl; delete [] ptr; std::cout << "DeleterCalled " << std::endl; };`

Comment: Deleting null pointer is a no-op. I suspect they (wrongly) did the same thing for custom deleter.